# Array in array dictionary for word spinning

Tags: php, arrays

There is a dictionary like this:

```
<?php
    $dic = array(
    " Hello" => " Hi ",
    " Bye " => " Goodbye ",
    " abacus " => " abacus ",
    " abaft " => " aback "
);
?>
```

and I used this function for replacing words in article;

```
$artarray = $article;
     $step1 = array("(", ")", "[", "]", "?", ".", ",", "|", "\$", "*", "+", "^","{", "}");
     $artarray = str_replace($step1," ",$artarray);
     $artarray = str_replace("  "," ",$artarray);
     $words_artarray = explode(" ",$artarray);

        if (sizeof($words_artarray)>0)
        {
        for($i=0;$i<sizeof($words_artarray);$i++)
            {
            $to_be_replaced = $words_artarray[$i];
            $to_be_replaced = str_replace(" ","",$to_be_replaced);

            if(($to_be_replaced!="")&&(strlen($to_be_replaced)>=4))
                {

                $to_be_replaced = " ".$to_be_replaced." ";
                $to_be_replaced_with = $dic[$to_be_replaced];
                if(($to_be_replaced!="")&&($to_be_replaced!=" ")&&($to_be_replaced_with!=""))
                    {
                    $article = str_replace($to_be_replaced,$to_be_replaced_with,$article);
                    $article = str_replace(" ".ucfirst(trim($to_be_replaced))." "," ".ucfirst(trim($to_be_replaced_with))." ",$article);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    $article = str_replace("\'","'",$article);
    $article = str_replace('\"','"',$article);
    echo '<textarea class="field w-input" id="textarea" rows="10">'.$article.'</textarea>';
```

This function works like an article spinner.
How can I use more than one word for spinning in dictionary and how to change the function?

Comment: *more than one word*... you want an array or any others words pairs or two+ words instead of one?

Comment: Thanks @AksenP ; Yes, I mean when I Use "Hello" in my article , I need a randomly selected "Hi" or "Hi there" or "Hi Honey"; I don't know how to add it in my dictionary file and how to change the function to be able to work!

Comment: This is the source of code:
https://github.com/briannaflemings/articlespinner

Comment: In fact, you need each time load the dictionary for searching some one keyword, which has a several replacements, or create a new one dictionary with nested arrays of replacements for each keyword. Performance of the first one is quite low.